# ionic/Cordova - Play local video file on IOS

Tags: ios, video, ionic-framework

I'm trying to play a local mp4 video file on IOS using ionic framework, but with no success (it works fine on android).
I'm using the cordova plugin Cordova FileOpener2. The file is a mp4 video file, encoded for IOS platform. here is my code :

```
 $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
      $cordovaFileOpener2.open(
         "/path/to/my/video",
         'video/mp4'
      ).then(function() {
          console.log("success");
      }, function(err) {
          console.log(err);
      });
 });
```

It works fine on android, but on IOS (tested with an iPhone 6s +) instead of playing the video with the native IOS video player, it shows me a choice tab with some options like "share with" or "upload to cloud" etc..

So, how can i play a local mp4 video file on IOS with ionic/cordova ?